# Get sibling of an XML node with XPath

Tags: java, xpath

I have the following XML

```
    <field label="mapping">
       <tuple> <atom label="A"/> <atom label="X"/> </tuple>
       <tuple> <atom label="B"/> <atom label="Y"/> </tuple>
       <tuple> <atom label="C"/> <atom label="Z"/> </tuple>
    </field>
```

I want to select the label of the second `atom` node from a `tuple` when I know the label of the other `atom`.

For example, if I know the `atom` with the label A, I want to get the atom with the label X.

I wrote this XPath expression, but it doesn't do the trick:

```
//following-sibling::field[@label = 'mapping']/tuple/atom[@label = 'A']
```

If I write

```
XPath expr = xpath.compile("//following-sibling::field[@label = 'mapping']/tuple/atom[@label = 'A']");
NodeList nodes = ((NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET));
for (int j=0;j<nodes.getLength();j++){
    String label = nodes.item(j).getAttributes().getNamedItem("label").getNodeValue();
}
```

the variable `label` is A, when I expect it to be X.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `following-sibling` axis in the wrong place, but that's close:

```
//field[@label = 'mapping']/tuple/atom[@label = 'A']/following-sibling::atom
```

Comment: Oh wow! Didn't see that. Thanks! It works, but now I feel stupid.